Renew command \chapter raises error
I have the following MWE that raises error, but I cannot find how to solve it. With the code, I need:

All pages to be numbered after the TOC (including the pages where chapters begin)
Chapter titles uppercased and boldfaced (both in TOC and in text)
Sections boldfaced (both in TOC and in text)
Subsections boldfaced and italic (both in TOC and in text)
Subsubsections italic (both in TOC and in text)

How to fix the code?
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, openright]{memoir}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%----------> SETUP TOC <----------%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%--> Change TOC title
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}

%--> Change TOC title style
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\fontsize{12}{12}\bfseries\centering}

%--> Remove vertical space before TOC title
\renewcommand{\chapterheadstart}{}

%--> Remove vertical space after TOC title
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{-1\baselineskip}}

%--> Add dotted lines for chapter levels in TOC
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}

%--> Adjust the alignment of the levels in TOC
\cftsetindents{part}{0em}{3.5em}
\cftsetindents{chapter}{0em}{3.5em}
\cftsetindents{section}{0em}{3.5em}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{0em}{3.5em}
\cftsetindents{subsubsection}{0em}{3.5em}

\newcommand{\TableOfContents}{%
    \cleardoublepage %... inicia próxima página ímpar
    
    %... Fazer sumário listar até subseções (tocdepth=4)
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
    
    \tableofcontents* %... o asterisco previne o sumário de listar-se a si mesmo
        \thispagestyle{empty}
    
    \cleardoublepage

    \setlength{\parindent}{1.3cm}
    %... ajusta a indentação de parágrafo de texto após o sumário
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%---------> SETUP TITLES <--------%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \fancyhf{}                           %... clears headers and footers
    \fancyhead[LE, RO]{\small\thepage}   %... page numbering
    \fancyhead[LO]{\small\rightmark}     %... section title
    \fancyhead[RE]{\small\rightmark}     %... section title
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\textbf{\thesection~#1}}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt} %... header line width

\usepackage{titlesec}

%--> Format titles in text
\titleformat{\chapter}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thechapter}{0.4em}{\MakeUppercase}
\titleformat{\section}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesection}{0.4em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\itshape}{\thesubsection}{0.4em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}{\thesubsubsection}{0.4em}{}

%--> Format titles in TOC
\let\newchapter\chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}[1]{%
    \newchapter{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
    \thispagestyle{fancy}
}

\let\newsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{%
    \newsection{\textbf{#1}}
}

\let\newsubsection\subsection
\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{%
    \newsubsection{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}
}

\let\newsubsubsection\subsubsection
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}[1]{%
    \newsubsubsection{\textit{#1}}
}

%--> Configure numbering levels
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%------> SETUP REFERENCES <-------%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{cite}

\nobibintoc
%... removes automatic title in TOC

%--> New command to generate bibliography
\newcommand*\MakeBibliography{%
    \cleardoublepage
    %... begins new odd page
    
    \renewcommand{\bibname}{TABLE OF REFERENCES}
    %... changes reference title
    
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}\bibname}
    %... add reference title to TOC
    
    \titleformat{\chapter}%
        {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\centering}{}{}{}
        %... formats font and positioning of references title
    
    %... make sure the \leftmark and the \rightmark will be printed correctly
    \phantomsection
    
    %... make sure the bibliography pages will be fancy
    \def\thispagestyle##1{}
    
    \bibliographystyle{abntex2-num}
    %... aplica a norma ABNT às referências
    
    \bibliography{_bib}
    %... gera as referências bibliográficas
}


\begin{document}

    \TableOfContents
    
    \chapter{This is the first chapter}
    In this chapter I will present some concepts...
    
    \section{Title of the first section}
    You can confirm the concepts by looking at the references.\cite{Ref1}
    
    \subsection{The amazing subsection}
    
    \subsubsection{Ordinary subsubsection}
    
    \MakeBibliography

\end{document}


I'm not sure you should use titlesec with memoir which has its own mechanisms.  Also \let\newsection\section \renewcommand{\section} isn't a safe redefinition for any latex command, use \NewCommandCopy  not \let

Thank you @DavidCarlisle for the comment. I am not expert in LaTeX, so I would appreciate a lot if you can provide a MWE that helps me analyse and uderstand.

firstly you should remove \let\newsection\section \renewcommand{\section}[1]{%     \newsection{\textbf{#1}} }   apart from \let not being safe way to redefine latex commands you do not want this definition, this forces the \textbf everywhere, in the table of contents and page head not just the section head itself. You have already specified the heading is bold with \titleformat{\section}% so it's doing nothing useful.

Actually it is doing something useful: this was the only way I found to force boldface in TOC.

eek no don't do it that way:-) memoir has extensive facilities for formatting the table of contents see section 9 of the memoir manual

I can't find another way. How can I do this? I searched a lot, but found no answer.

I don't really know memoir but looking at the manual you don't want to load titlesec or redefine the commands but just define for example \cftsectionfontfont to be \bfseries see page 155

All of this is listed in the memoir manual. Please explain (1), and note that you probably need to load a font with bold small caps, not sure the default font provides the combination.

And you should not use fancyhdr with memoir either, the build in page styles in memoir is far better integrated than what fancyhdr can provide.
